# git в чем отличие команд git checkout

Tags: git

в чем отличие команд:

- `git checkout HEAD .`
- `git checkout -f HEAD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если рабочее дерево или индекс будет отличаться от HEAD, переключение на ветку/тег/коммит продолжится при наличии флага f.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--f

Точка в конце говороит о том, что файлы будут возвращены к HEAD только в текущем дереве(т.е. в текущей папке и во вложенных)

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_description